# java riddle undefined variable

Tags: java, compiler-errors, undefined

we got the following riddle in class and so far it is unsolved.

```
Public Class T {
//...
i=10;
i=i+1;
//..
}
```

you must fill the missing code so when compiled in java jdk1.8 only the following error will occur during compilation:

i = **i** + 1; i is unidentified or unknown symbol
the point is that only the bolded i produces the bug and deleting this row will make the code compileable 
we have tried some clever manipulation but no success so far
we have tried to follwing code

```
for(int i=9;i<10;i++) 
i = 10;
i = i + 1;
```

but we got unidentified on the unbolded i as well
can someone help us?

Comment: `no success` Is not the proper description of a problem, you need to include the code you tried and tell us what doesn't work, why, what is the expected behaviour and what is happening instead. I strongly doubt that just removing that line will make the code compile. For example, the class definition is wrong and it won't compile: please post all the actual code.

Comment: "only the following error will occur:" - What error exactly?  If `i` is unidentified, it won't compile to produce an error.

Comment: @SteveSmith we meant that the code wont compile....
pretty sure it was obvious that the error of no comiplation will occur.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error that you want to create?

Comment: Just put it in a block? `{ i = i + 1; }`

Comment: How can it be possible to get an error on `i` in the `i+1` expression but not the `i` before that? If `i` is unidentified then it will cause an error on `i  = ...` before `i+1` even happens.

Comment: Putting it in a block would require also declaring the variable inside the block.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you cant edit the part that you are trying to edit

Comment: @Yuval David That's right, but I'm trying to understand your question.  You say "you must fill the missing code so when compiled in java jdk1.8 only the following error will occur:  "i = i + 1; i is unidentified or unknown".  But you won't get this error *after* compilation, only during.

Comment: @SteveSmith yea you will get the variable undefined error during compilation

Comment: @Yuval David - "fill the missing code so when compiled in java jdk1.8 only the following error will occur" - what error exactly?

Comment: @SteveSmith already posted the solution you were too slow XD and the i cannot be resolve to a variable error

Answer (score 0):

```
static{
        i=10;
        i=i+1;
    }
    static int i;
```

well this is the solution ty for your help stackoverflow :) you almost solved it and had alot of bad ideas